# animate and LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, animate

why i got error:

```
undefined control sequence
<argument> luatexversion
                         <95
l.924
```

for this simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
here is nothing to animate!
\end{document}
```

when compiling with pdfLateX. closing compilation editor open file `pdfbase.sty`.

I have recent 64-bit MikteX and this test has been working no so far ago.

Comment: apparently the package is expecting lualatex

Comment: it seems so, but so far animate works without lualatex.

Comment: I don't get the error message with `pdflatex` on TL17 (Linux)

Comment: Yeah, works fine for me, also.  What do you mean by `closing compilation editor open file pdfbase.sty`?

Comment: when compilation stop, i hit `x` key and then editor open `pdfbase.sty` file and show line in it, where he find this undefined control sequence

Comment: Looks like a bug in the package.  It runs some code for lualatex compilation while in pdflatex mode.  I'd suggest trying to update to the latest version and failing that writing to the package author.

Comment: This has already been fixed last week.

Comment: @AlexG, nice to hear this. unfortunately my miktex upgrade crash, and now i'm busy with it re-installation. when finish, i will notice, if now work as expected :)

Comment: after reinstalling MikTeX, `animate` works. however, its version is (still) `2017/05/18` :(, so I don't know, if the file is new or old ...

Comment: Because it was `pdfbase.sty`, a requirement of `animate` and part of `media9`, that needed fixing.

Comment: thank you very much again. i learn something new ... and spend almost all day for restoring my latex installation , one small (my) error cause so many problems :(